# Query for subclass of a component in Ext JS

Tags: extjs, extjs4.2, component-query

I have a panel **A** with only one child with *Ext.panel.Panel* (or its direct or indirect sub-classes, like *Ext.panel.Table*, *Ext.grid.Panel*, or any custom classes) type. I want to query for this child of **A**. How can i do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Provided that xtype of panel A would be `mypanela` then you can get its items (and subitems) with:

```
Ext.ComponentQuery.query('mypanela panel');
```

If you only want the direct child then:

```
Ext.ComponentQuery.query('mypanela > panel');
```

Answer (score 0):

If you has not defined xtype for class A, your class is still instance of Component. So, you can to use code like this:

```
Ext.ComponentQuery.query('box[$className=MyWin] panel')
```

You can see live example here:

https://fiddle.sencha.com/fiddle/993/